# Creating a while loop to run a select statement against a list of DBs within the same server

Tags: sql, while-loop

We have servers with 100 DBs each.  I want to run a select statement on approximately 50-75 of the databases on each server.

I can write a select statement to put the necessary DBs into a temp table.

From there I want to run a while loop that loops through each DB and runs the select statement, so that I can figure out which DBs have this active account.  It needs to be run regularly which is why I am not just doing it manually.

Here is what I have.  It gives me an error on my 'USE' command, saying incorrect syntax near @hospuse

```
DECLARE @hospcounter INT; 
DECLARE @hospuse varchar(100);
DECLARE @userlogin varchar(50);
SET @hospcounter = 0;
SET @hospuse = (select name from #tempdbnames where hospnumber = '1')
SET @userlogin = 'dmarch'

SELECT IDENTITY(int, 1,1) AS hospnumber, name into #tempdbnames
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
where name NOT LIKE ('%storage_0%')
AND NAME NOT LIKE ('%WSR%')
AND name NOT LIKE ('Z%')
AND name NOT LIKE ('master')
AND name NOT LIKE ('model')
AND name NOT LIKE ('msdb')
AND name NOT LIKE ('tempdb')
AND name NOT LIKE ('_Placeholder')




WHILE @hospcounter <= (select MAX(hospnumber) from #tempdbnames)
BEGIN
USE @hospuse
SELECT ro.user_login, ro.activated from rev_operator ro where   ro.user_login = @userlogin and ro.activated != '0'

SET @hospcounter = @hospcounter + 1;
SET @hospuse = (select name from #tempdbnames where hospnumber = @hospcounter);
END;

PRINT 'Done';
GO
```

drop table #tempdbnames

I also tried this with sp_msforeachdb but couldn't figure out how to get the syntax right for filtering the DBs I wanted to use without literally saying NOT IN and listing every DB I didn't want.  Which doesn't work because DBs get added regularly.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to run the same query across multiple databases, cursors actually will be a good option.

```
DECLARE @Databases Table (DBName varchar(256))
DECLARE @Name varchar(256)
DECLARE @SQL Nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @userlogin varchar(50)
SET @userlogin = 'dmarch'

INSERT @Databases
select name from sys.databases where  name NOT LIKE ('%storage_0%')
AND NAME NOT LIKE ('%WSR%')
AND name NOT LIKE ('Z%')
AND name NOT LIKE ('master')
AND name NOT LIKE ('model')
AND name NOT LIKE ('msdb')
AND name NOT LIKE ('tempdb')
AND name NOT LIKE ('_Placeholder')




DECLARE DBCursor Cursor For
Select DBName
from @Databases

OPEN DBCursor
FETCH NEXT
FROM DBCursor
INTO @Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

SET @SQL = N'USE ['+@Name+'] 
select ''['+@Name+']'',  ro.user_login, ro.activated from rev_operator ro where ro.user_login = @userlogin and ro.activated != ''0'''

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL


FETCH NEXT
      FROM DBCursor
      INTO @Name
END

CLOSE DBCursor
DEALLOCATE DBCursor
```

Comment: I'm getting this.

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
Invalid object name 'rev_operator'.

Comment: Retooled original answer, which did not include some necessary dynamic SQL, my apologies. Try that, if the error persists then it sounds like some incorrect databases are being inserted into the table, I'd check the WHERE clause to make sure all database we don't want the query running on are being filtered

Comment: For some reason the query isn't recognizing the @userlogin variable.  So I just put the user login into the query directly with two sets of single quotes.  This has resolved the issue.  Thank you so much for the query.

Comment: I don't suppose it's easy to make it only output the databases where there is a result.  This works great and is a big help, but generally I expect to find 1 or 2 results out of like a list of 170 mostly blank results.

Comment: You can can plug in an IF clause right below the N'USE [+Name+'] line. Something like
`SET @SQL = N'USE ['+@Name+'] 
IF (select count(*) from rev_operator ro where ro.user_login = @userlogin and ro.activated != ''0'') > 0
select ''['+@Name+']'',  ro.user_login, ro.activated from rev_operator`...etc

This way the select query will only run if your criteria returns a result

Comment: Thank you very much, sqlnick,

The @username variable still doesn't work, but just putting in the username instead works fine.  Your tweak for adding the IF statement worked as well.

I really appreciate all the responses.